# I have an array list in java of String tables and I want to delete empty and null elements from those tables

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list of String tables like this:

```
[Hello, , Jack] //String table[0]
[] // String table[1]
```

How can I remove empty and null elements to be:

```
[Hello, Jack] //String table[0]
```

Comment: `list.removeIf(s -> s == null || s.isEmpty());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Java8+, you can do the following:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

list.add(new String[]{"Hello", "", null, "Jack"});
list.add(new String[]{});

for(String[] array : list){
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
    arrayList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    arrayList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
    array = arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an `ArrayList<String[]>`, you can use [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) to remove `null` (or empty) elements in the `List`:

```
list.removeIf(table -> table == null || table.length == 0);
```

To remove `null` or empty elements from the arrays themselves, you'll have to rebuild the arrays without them:

```
list.replaceAll(table -> Arrays.stream(table)
                               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                               .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                               .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I think he has List<String[]> and use 'Table' for 'array'

Comment: @azro I reckon it could even be a `List<String>[]`

Comment: yeah i use ArrayList<String[]> myList= new ArrayList<String[]>();

Comment: @StavrosArgyrides Thanks for letting me know :) I'll edit my answer.  Are you looking to remove `null` and empty elements from every array, or just the first?  It seems you're also looking to remove empty arrays as well.

Comment: yes ...actually i read from a file a text like "Hello, Jack. How is it going? Not Bad;pretty good,actually... Very very good, in fact." and my results are :[Hello, , Jack]
[, How, is, it, going]
[, Not, Bad, pretty, good, actually]
[]
[]
[, Very, very, good, , in, fact]

Comment: and i want to be : [Hello,  Jack]
[How, is, it, going]
[Not, Bad, pretty, good, actually]
[Very, very, good, in, fact]

Comment: I see.  I just edited my answer with an alternative solution that should work for you.  The top snippet removes `null` elements in the `List` itself, and the bottom snippet removes `null` and empty (`""`) elements within the arrays themselves.